# Will SQL Server clustered columnstore index be affected by incremental load

Tags: sql-server, database

We are building a restaurant data warehouse in SQL Server 2016 and are considering whether to use a clustered columnstore index for the FactSales table.

Every time a guest check (i.e. customer bill) is closed, those sales are loaded into FactSales, which could therefore have data loaded every minute. At the same time SSRS reports will run off this table.

It is not just FactSales sales that gets loaded each time -- about 5 fact tables do.

Is the clustered columnstore index still a good choice with the way we are planning to load the data warehouse.

Comment: Everytime it is going to be delta load or full load?

Comment: If it is delta load what will be load size(in records counts) for each delta?

Comment: I think it depends on the total number of records, if you have lots of data pages, you may have big number of index fragmentation later, may need to rebuild or reorganize frequently

Comment: Restaurant -> low transaction volume. You shouldn't worry at all *except* for the fact that the delta store is processed when it reaches 1M rows. You should probably add a maintenance job to rebuild the columnstore index every day

Comment: delta load -- only the checks that have just closed will be added
load size: up to 150 -200 checks per minutes. At 15-20 rows per check. Can be up to 4000 rows per minute